# Border/Shadow to remain after click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a something like a store, so I have the product and there is circle buttons on the side and when I click on them it changes the color of the product. Everything works perfect but I want when I click on the button, the button to remain highligted. The code:

```
<img src="../../CONTENT/Images/Blizuk/New folder/11.png" onclick= "change()" id="but1">
<img src="../../CONTENT/Images/Blizuk/New folder/14.png" onclick = "change2()" id="but2"> 
<img src="../../CONTENT/Images/Blizuk/New folder/12.png" onclick = "change3()" id="but3">
```

css:

```
#but1 {
position:absolute;
width:5%;   
border:none;
margin-top:13%;
left:12%;   
}

#but1:hover {
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1));
filter: url(#drop-shadow);    
}

#but2 {
position:absolute;
width:5%;   
border:none;
margin-top:13%;
left:17%;   
}

#but2:hover {
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1));
filter: url(#drop-shadow);    
}

#but3 {
position:absolute;
width:5%;   
border:none;
margin-top:13%;
left:22%;   
}

#but3:hover {
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1));
filter: url(#drop-shadow);
}
```

The script:

```
<script>
function change(){
clothing.src = "../../CONTENT/Images/Blizuk/New folder/1.png"; 
}
function change2(){
clothing.src = "../../CONTENT/Images/Blizuk/New folder/2.png"; 
}
function change3(){
clothing.src = "../../CONTENT/Images/Blizuk/New folder/3.png"; 
}

</script>
```

Comment: What is inside `clothing` var? Can you provide working SO Snippet to look closer to?

Comment: Inside clothing are Images. So when I click on the button it shows PNG file of the product so that its not important. I just want the buttons the remain highlighted it doesn't matter with border or shadow.

Comment: This sounds like a good application for custom radio buttons.

Comment: can you create https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

this solution can be improved of course but following your html structure and for you to understand easily wrote this.

```
 function change(){
      clothing.src = "../../CONTENT/Images/Blizuk/New folder/1.png";
      document.getElementById("butt1").style.border = "1px solid red"; 
    }
    function change2(){
     clothing.src = "../../CONTENT/Images/Blizuk/New folder/2.png";
      document.getElementById("butt2").style.border = "1px solid red"; 

       document.getElementById("butt1").style.border = "none";
       document.getElementById("butt3").style.border = "none";  

    }
function change3(){
     clothing.src = "../../CONTENT/Images/Blizuk/New folder/3.png";
      document.getElementById("butt3").style.border = "1px solid red"; 
       document.getElementById("butt2").style.border = "none";  

       document.getElementById("butt1").style.border = "none";  


}
```

Comment: This works, but after I select other button this remains highlighted. I have 4 buttons so after I click on all 4 it ALL remain highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to pass parameter to `change()` functions. Check below snippet for reference.

```js
function change(clothing) {
  clothing.src = "http://convertimage.net/frontframe/images/cute_ball_info.png";
  clothing.className += 'highlightMe';
}
```

```css
#butt1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5%;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 13%;
  left: 12%;
}

#butt1:hover {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
  filter: url(#drop-shadow);
}

#butt2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5%;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 13%;
  left: 17%;
}

#butt2:hover {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
  filter: url(#drop-shadow);
}

#butt3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5%;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 13%;
  left: 22%;
}

#butt3:hover {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
  filter: url(#drop-shadow);
}

.highlightMe {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" onclick="change(this)" id="butt1">
```

Answer (score 0):

to highlight a button on click you can add a class to itself upon click... You would usually also loop over all buttons dynamically and get the content you want to display either from a JSON or inline data attributes. I'll give you an example..

https://jsfiddle.net/9d25k66a/

You create a few buttons with one and the same class to nicely select them with jQuery or vanilla JavaScript as following:

```
<button class="btn" data-activeimage="red" >Button 1</button>
<button class="btn" data-activeimage="green">Button 2</button>
<button class="btn" data-activeimage="blue">Button 3</button>
```

You also add data, that you want to display on that button directly into the html, to not have to hardcore anything in your javaScript. There are millions ways to do it but the following short JS Code will show you why this for example is handy.

```
// you select ALL the buttons by selecting all elements with the class .btn
// $buttons is now a jQuery Array which can be iterated over or mapped over with either a regular for loop or the jQuery each method
var $buttons = $('.btn');

// here we loop over all elements that we've stored in the $buttons variable
$buttons.each(function(idx){
    // and attach a click event to each one of them
    $(this).on("click", function(e){
    // preventing default button behaviour of e.g. Form Submit etc
    e.preventDefault();
    // Using the elements data attribute to apply a backgroudn color that is defined in the data-activeimage attribute of the html tag
    $(this).css('background-color', $(this).data('activeimage'))
  })
})
```

I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

try below code its working fine.

just add below mentioned css in you style sheet.

```
 to add in style sheet : 
.hightLight {border: 5px solid #000 !important;}

html code
<img src="images/logo.png" id="butt1">

java script code
  <script>
$("#butt1").click(function() {
$(this).addClass("hightLight");
});
```